# How to get the final value in one of the columns generated by For Loop in a New Column?

Tags: vba, for-loop, flat-file

I am using VBA. The For() Loop in my progam is:

```
        For i = 5 To 23
            Status$ = GetScreen(4,i,3)
            DateofDPS$=GetScreen(12,i,8)
            TimeofStatus$=GetScreen(23,i,8)
            TypeofDPS$=GetScreen(34,i,8)
            Tech$=GetScreen(41,i,8)
            techName$=GetScreen(50,i,30)

            If Asc(GetScreen(43,i,6))<>32 Then
                Write #OutputFile, DPSNo$, Status$,DateofDPS$,TimeofStatus$,TypeofDPS$,Tech$,techName$
            Else
            End If
        Next i
```

The result stored in the #OutputFile is

```
Num |   STAT    |   DAT         |   TIM         |   TYP |   TEC |   techName
----+-----------+---------------+---------------+-------+-------+------------
477 |   P       |   12/17/2014  |   17:20:34    |   EX  |   175 |   UME 
477 |   I       |   12/17/2014  |   17:40:47    |   EX  |   255 |   VIN 
477 |   O       |   12/17/2014  |   17:40:58    |   EX  |   255 |   VIN 
804 |   P       |   12/11/2014  |   11:01:39    |   EX  |   207 |   KAU 
804 |   I       |   12/11/2014  |   14:34:07    |   EX  |   253 |   JOS 
804 |   O       |   12/11/2014  |   14:34:26    |   EX  |   253 |   JOS 
402 |   P       |   11/13/2014  |   22:08:50    |   EX  |   243 |   SHA 
402 |   I       |   11/14/2014  |   05:04:04    |   EX  |   247 |   LAK 
402 |   O       |   11/14/2014  |   05:04:08    |   EX  |   247 |   LAK
```

I want to add another column finalAction and the result should look like:

```
Num |   STAT    |   DAT         |   TIM         |   TYP |   TEC |   techName    |   finaAction
----+-----------+---------------+---------------+-------+-------+---------------+-------------
477 |   P       |   12/17/2014  |   17:20:34    |   EX  |   175 |   UME         |   VIN
477 |   I       |   12/17/2014  |   17:40:47    |   EX  |   255 |   VIN         |   VIN
477 |   O       |   12/17/2014  |   17:40:58    |   EX  |   255 |   VIN         |   VIN
804 |   P       |   12/11/2014  |   11:01:39    |   EX  |   207 |   KAU         |   JOS
804 |   I       |   12/11/2014  |   14:34:07    |   EX  |   253 |   JOS         |   JOS
804 |   O       |   12/11/2014  |   14:34:26    |   EX  |   253 |   JOS         |   JOS
402 |   P       |   11/13/2014  |   22:08:50    |   EX  |   243 |   SHA         |   LAK  
402 |   I       |   11/14/2014  |   05:04:04    |   EX  |   247 |   LAK         |   LAK  
402 |   O       |   11/14/2014  |   05:04:08    |   EX  |   247 |   LAK         |   LAK
```

The For() Loop writes to a Flat File.

I want to add the Final Name in techName Column and repeat the same.

Any way of doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First option that comes to mind:

create a variable to hold "LastDPONo"
then watch for a change between the current record DPONo$ and the "LastDPONo" value.

When a change occurs you have found your last record for that DPONo$ and you can then identify the Tech$ assigned to the last update on that DPSNo$

You will either need to identify the correct Tech$ before writing your rows out to the output file or you will have to modify the output file once you find the Tech$ value.

1. If you wish to identify the Tech$ first you could write the data for
   each row to an array or Recordset as you look for the last
   consecutive row of a DPSNo$ to find the Tech$ you need. Once you
   find the Tech$ you can loop through the array or recordset you
   created and write the value of each entity o the array or record of
   the recordset into your output file with the Tech$ added at the end.
2. To modify the text file you can add an extra column and then adapt a
   method outlined here:
   http://software-solutions-online.com/2014/03/15/vba-modify-existing-text-file/#Jump2

Comment: Thank you @IAWeir. It was a brilliant idea I changed my For () Loop as follows and it worked:
   For i = 5 To 23
    Status$ = GetScreen(4,i,3)
    DateofDPS$=GetScreen(12,i,8)
    TimeofStatus$=GetScreen(23,i,8)
    TypeofDPS$=GetScreen(34,i,8)
    Tech$=GetScreen(41,i,8)
    techName$=GetScreen(50,i,30)
    If Asc(techName$)=32 Then
     finalActionBy$=GetScreen(41,i-1,8)
    Else
    End If
    If Asc(GetScreen(43,i,6))<>32 Then
     Write #OutputFile, DPSNo$, Status$,DateofDPS$,TimeofStatus$,TypeofDPS$,Tech$,techName$,creaBy$,creaByName$,finalActionBy$
    Else
    End If
   Next i